# Неправильно срабатывает проверка условия

Tags: php, if

Язык PHP. Ставлю условие. Если $format !== "m" || $format !== "h" то выводим ошибку. но даже если $format равен m или h то все равно пишет что неверный формат.
Делаю var_dump($format) и выводит string(1) "m"

```
if($format !== "m" || $format !== "h"){
        $sender->sendMessage("Используйте только эти форматы времени: m (минуты) или h (часы)");
        $this->getLogger()->info("DEBUG >> отменили действие потому что формат неверен");
        $this->getLogger()->info("DEBUG >> $nick $time $format $reason");
        $this->getLogger()->info("DEBUG >> nick:");
        var_dump($nick);
        $this->getLogger()->info("DEBUG >> player:");
        var_dump($player);
        $this->getLogger()->info("DEBUG >> time:");
        var_dump($time);
        $this->getLogger()->info("DEBUG >> format:");
        var_dump($format);
        $this->getLogger()->info("DEBUG >> reason:");
        var_dump($reason);
        return false;
   }
```

Comment: вы присвойте значение `$format = "m"` прямо перед if и проверьте. потом небось окажется что данные в утф приходят, а пхп файл с сп1251 сохранен

Comment: окей сейчас попробую

Comment: что не в тот край меня понесло.  `||` на `&&` замените

Comment: вы когда пишите `m` то у вас срабатывает вторая часть условия при проверке на h

Comment: Честно говоря, меня немного клинит при виде `logger->info("debug"); var_dump($value);`... Это отладочное или информационное сообщение? Почему значение пишется не в лог?

Comment: отладочное. делал чтобы разобраться, почему условие не работало

Answer (score 0):

```
$allowFormat = ['m','h'];


if(!in_array($format, $allowFormat)){
        $sender->sendMessage("Используйте только эти форматы времени: m (минуты) или h (часы)");
        $this->getLogger()->info("DEBUG >> отменили действие потому что формат неверен");
        $this->getLogger()->info("DEBUG >> $nick $time $format $reason");
        $this->getLogger()->info("DEBUG >> nick:");
        var_dump($nick);
        $this->getLogger()->info("DEBUG >> player:");
        var_dump($player);
        $this->getLogger()->info("DEBUG >> time:");
        var_dump($time);
        $this->getLogger()->info("DEBUG >> format:");
        var_dump($format);
        $this->getLogger()->info("DEBUG >> reason:");
        var_dump($reason);
        return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы понимаете, что само выражение `($format !== "m" || $format !== "h")` всегда будет равно `true`? $format всегда НЕ равно чему-нибудь из двух значений, даже если оно равно одному из них.